# SWT folder '..\framework\x86' does not exist. Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform

Tags: java, android, python, testing, monkeyrunner

i try to run my android test script by "monkeyrunner cameraTest.py"
but it can't work, the cmd show me this

SWT folder '..\framework\x86' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.

anyone know how to deal with this？thanks

Comment: Vote on this issue on github https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-perf-testing/issues/50

Answer (score 2):

Hope http://blog.csdn.net/zjabc520/article/details/76043741 can help you.

modify：

```
for /f %%a in ("%APP_HOME%\lib\monkeyrunner-25.3.2.jar") do set jarfile=%%~nxa
set frameworkdir=.
set libdir=

**rem if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk**

**rem   set frameworkdir=lib**

**rem if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk**

**rem   set frameworkdir=..\framework**

rem add this

**set frameworkdir=..\lib**

:JarFileOk
```

and then run monkeyrunner,it'll happen adb not found.

next step：

go to your tools folder,create folder name framework.Then copy the adb.exe into framework folder.finally run monkeyrunner again.

good luck

Comment: You are a life saver man, I was trying to do that for more than two days. You saved my week. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ohbo's solution, copying AdbWinApi.dll, AdbWinUsbApi.dll into framework folder solved my problem.